# How to link a 64bit dll file on linux using mingw

Tags: linux, windows-7, 64-bit, dll, mingw64

I try to compile and link a *.c file (to use with the [jni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)) on linux to target windows 64bit with [mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/). I do

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -I"path/to/headers" -shared -o output.dll input.c
```

Everything compiles and I get a 64bit *.dll as `file output.dll` shows:

```
output.dll: PE32+ executable (DLL) (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

But on my 64bit windows java throws an Unsatisfied link error because some libraries,  my dll depends on, are missing. So I downloaded [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and opened the dll file. It shows me that the *.dll file is linked with the 32bit (x86) versions of the dlls I depend on instead the 64 bit dlls. Only my dll is 64bit (x64). I looked into `C:\Windows` and found out that also the 64bit dlls are present.

So I tried to fix this by adjusting the arguments in the mingw command. In the manual-entry for ld I found option -L to specify a path dependencies. So I tried the following:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wl,-L"/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/" -I"path/to/headers" -shared -o output.dll input.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wl,-L"/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/",-static -I"path/to/headers" -shared -o output.dll input.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wl,-static -I"path/to/headers" -shared -o output.dll input.c
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -m64 -I"path/to/headers" -shared -o output.dll input.c
```

Note: `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/` is the directory where mingw's 64bit *.a files are located.

The above commands didn't seem to have any effect on my output dll. It stays 64 bit but linked to 32bit dlls. I have no idea what to do to get this work.

Also when I compile this for 32 bit using `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` everything works fine and I get a 32bit dll linked with the 32bit dlls in windows.

My windows is windows 7 home premium and I use java 11 by the way.

**EDIT:** I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737612/linking-64bit-dll-mingw) question but the answer doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have no idea why it didn't work. When I tried again 3 days later, the command

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wl,-L"/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/" -I"path/to/headers" -shared -o output.dll input.c
```

works perfectly fine. So if you have the same issue, I'd recommend to reboot your computer and try the command above.